# Springboot framwork spring web issue

Tags: java, gradle, web, frameworks

Hi I was having an issue related to vulnerabilities check and seems like spring framework's spring web 5.3.25.jar has vulnerability. I want it to be upgraded to 6.0.0 but it seems like only java 17 and above is supported. we are only working with java 11. Is there a way to just upgrade the part of springboot framework so that it could be compatible with java 11. or any other idea to not show that vulnerability. (gradle build)

```
type here
```

I tried excluding and got resttemplate error.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent here is to upgrade to a vulnerabilities free version then you can upgrade your spring boot to 2.7.18 as it has spring web 5.3.31 which doesn't have vulnerabilities. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/index.html.)

But it would be good to migrate to spring boot 3.x as even the commercial support for 2.x is going to expire soon.

refer to the migration guide for the same: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide